# Set standard format for Date

Tags: r, date, standards

I have table,

```
>dt
ID     Date
001   13-Jan-2016
002   2016-01-10
003   15-Jan-2016
004   2016-01-09
005   2016-01-11
```

and, I want to make my table like this

```
>dt
    ID     Date
    004   09-Jan-2016
    002   10-Jan-2016
    005   11-Jan-2016
    001   13-Jan-2016
    003   15-Jan-2016
```

I want to set default for the Date variable and make it order. What should I do? 
Thanks.

Comment: checkout the `lubridate` package, it provides various methods for standardizing dates

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have exactly the two formats you show, you can use `grepl` to look for letters, and use `ifelse` to pass `as.Date` a different format based on the result:

```
as.Date(dt$Date, ifelse(grepl('[a-z]', dt$Date), '%d-%b-%Y', '%Y-%m-%d'))
# [1] "2016-01-13" "2016-01-10" "2016-01-15" "2016-01-09" "2016-01-11"
```

If you overwrite `dt$Date`, you can use `order` to sort:

```
dt$Date <- as.Date(dt$Date, ifelse(grepl('[a-z]', dt$Date), '%d-%b-%Y', '%Y-%m-%d'))
dt[order(dt$Date),]

#    ID       Date
# 4 004 2016-01-09
# 2 002 2016-01-10
# 5 005 2016-01-11
# 1 001 2016-01-13
# 3 003 2016-01-15
```

Comment: After all this time I didn't realise you could specify a vector of formats to `as.Date()`. You learn something every day I suppose.

Comment: @alistaire - vector recycling - it is trying to format against `c('%d-%b-%Y', '%F')[c(1,2,1,2,1)]`

Comment: @alistaire thanks, that's so helpful.